# How can i change font of JS alert text

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

it might sound stupid but let me explain, i have this `ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript` and it does call a JS method which shows a pop up, I want to change the `font-family` of the text inside that pop up, how may i do it?

here is my code:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, typeof(Page),
"custom_alert", "swal({title: 'Alart',text: 'Please take a long look at the text, and try again',type: 'error',confirmButtonText: 'Okay'})",
true);
```

Comment: If your script is using the Javascript `window.alert` function, I'm not aware of any way to change that font.

But it looks to me as if you're using a Javascript framework of some kind, and its own custom alert functionality. In that case, the font probably is customizable.

Comment: If you tell us what framework you're using, we can probably help you figure out how to customize it.

Comment: Hello! @AnnL. Thank you for your reply ! I am using [sweetAlert.](http://t4t5.github.io/sweetalert)

Comment: Check out my answer, below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried just putting your font change in the `text` property itself?  I built this (which has not been tested!) from looking at an example on the `SweetAlert` webpage:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, typeof(Page),
       "custom_alert", 
       "swal({
          title: 'Alert', 
          text: '<span style="font-family:verdana">Please take a long look at the text, and try again</span>',
          type: 'error',
          confirmButtonText: 'Okay'})",
       true);
```

Also, I assume the title was meant to say "Alert" and not "Alart".  :)

It looks from the webpage as if you probably can associate a custom style sheet with your alerts, so you could have all your alerts looking consistent.  (You can also hack the style sheet that comes with it, but I don't recommend that.  Use a separate custom style sheet if it'll let you.)